# cURL and SMTP error after SSL and clodflare

Tags: ssl, curl, nginx, smtp, cloudflare

I have a wordpress site.Everything was running fine but after I activated SSL sertificate and Cloudflare things got messed up. 
I am trying to send emails via mailgun smtp. but I got this error.
[smtp error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMJws.jpg)

I googled for this one and I tried to change from google DNS to openDNS but no success

Also when I want to install a plugin these errors shows up
[install error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XskVZ.jpg)

However I can upload plugins manually so it should not be a permission issue.

I am running Nginx and here are my iptables
[iptables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ren3Z.jpg)

And to check ports Listening
[Listen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LuAlN.jpg)

Since this is curl error I tried to run:
curl -v https://mydomain.info

In a perfect world it should return html but I got this instead:

curl: (6) Could not resolve host: mydomain.info

If anyone has any idea where to look for answers I would really appreciate that.